# Extending a class in TypeScript and compiling to es5

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to do something pretty basic in TypeScript. I'm compiling the following script down to `es5`. I'm using TypeScript version 3.5.3 and node version 12.7.0

```
class MyString extends String {};
let a = new MyString("123");
console.log(a.toString());
```

And for some reason I am getting the following error:

```
/mnt/c/Users/odonn/Code/isolate/out/main.js:23
console.log(a.toString());
              ^

TypeError: String.prototype.toString requires that 'this' be a String
    at MyString.toString (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/odonn/Code/isolate/out/main.js:23:15)
```

I figured this could be a bug in TypeScript. But I figured I would post here first so that if it's something that I'm doing wrong, then other people can learn from my mistake.

Comment: You cannot extend the built in types in ES5. Well, you can try but it's not likely to work

Comment: @VLAZ Isn't TypeScript supposed to handle that though?

Comment: [It's a known bug and/or limitation of ES5](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27602)

Comment: @artem Super helpful, thank you for linking that